# How to check image exist on server or not in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I have a recent article section where i need to validate whether image is exist or not on server.

I try some tutorial it validate properly but it does not return any value to my ng-if directive.

Here is my recent article section:-

```
 <div ng-controller="RecentCtrl">

        <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="items in data.data" data-ng-class="{'last': ($index+1)%4 == 0}" bh-bookmark="items" bh-redirect>
                                                        <div class="forHoverInner">
   <span class="inner">
   <span class="defaultThumbnail">
<span ng-if="test(app.getEncodedUrl(items.bookmark_preview_image))" style="background-image: url('{{app.getEncodedUrl(items.bookmark_preview_image)}}'); width: 272px; height: 272px; " class="thumb" variant="2"></span></span></span> </div>
</div></div>
```

Here is my recent article controller:-

```
app.controller('RecentCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, RecentArticleFactory,$q) {
$scope.test = function(url) {
        RecentArticleFactory.isImage(url).then(function(result) {
            return result;
        });
    };

})
```

Here is recent aricle factory code:-

```
app.factory("RecentArticleFactory", ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {
 return {
isImage: function(src) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var image = new Image();
            image.onerror = function() {
                deferred.resolve(false);
            };
            image.onload = function() {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            };
            image.src = src;

            return deferred.promise;
        },
}

})
```

But

> ng-if="test(app.getEncodedUrl(items.bookmark_preview_image))" does not return any value

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because it is async due to deferred. Try calling the test function and binding the result value to a field in scope.

First, trigger the test function via `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch("data.data", function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.data.data.length; i++) {
        var items = $scope.data.data[i];
        $scope.test(items);
    }
})
```

Then change your `test` function as follows:

```
$scope.test = function(items) {
    items.isImageAvailable= false;
        RecentArticleFactory.isImage(items.bookmark_preview_image).then(function(result) {
            items.isImageAvailable= result;
        });
    };
})
```

Finally, you can use this in your view as:

```
<span ng-if="items.isImageAvailable" ...></span>
```

Of course you also need to call `app.getEncodedUrl` in between. But as I could not see, where `app` is defined, I omitted this. But the conversion is nevertheless necessary.

Comment: Can you provide me any example?

Comment: @arunkamboj: I updated my post with some additional code.

Comment: Are you sure that your check for image availability works in the first place? What exactly "is not working"?